# Invisible fullscreen button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

i want to figure out a solution for the problem, creating a button over nearly fullscreen, but independent of the other stuff i want to put in this layout. So like an invisible button, in which i can place for example an imageView or multiple imageViews.

Is this possible?

I am working with Android Studio 3.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int).

Comment: 1. Why? Not because your request is weird, but because our answer will differ depending on your purpose (make your outer layout clickable or overlay your view with a button). 2. Why do you want to put (invisible!) stuff inside an invisible button? Do you want to make it visible at one point (button click, for example)? 3. Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //float x = me.getX();
            //float y = me.getY();
            performClick();
            //enter your code here
        }
        return false;
    }
```